# Create SecurityKey from signing certificate thumbprint

Tags: c#, owin, wif, ws-federation

I'm trying to migrate from FederationAuthenticationModule (WS FAM?) to OWIN WsFederationAuthentication middleware. So far, so good except that, for some customers we only have the thumbprint of their signing certificate.

For WS FAM, this was enough as [`ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry.AddTrustedIssuer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.configurationbasedissuernameregistry.addtrustedissuer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only needs the thumbprint of the signing certificate.

The OWIN middleware however, needs a [`SecurityKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitykey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-derived type in the `WsFederationConfiguration.SigningKeys`-collection. While I can create a `SecurityKey` from a certificate, I can't find a way to create one from the thumbprint only.

Any ideas how I can create a `SecurityKey` from a certificate thumbprint only or any other way to get the WsFederationAuthentication middleware working with only thumbprints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, the easiest way to use WIF with owin is through the usage of the federation meta data (which lives at FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml).  Then you don't need to setup anything at all.  It's explained here: http://blog.baslijten.com/configure-claims-based-web-applications-using-owin-wsfederation-middleware/ .  The precondition is of course that your STS publishes a meaningful FederationMetaData document.  The nice advantage is that your public keys needed for validation are automatically picked up by your application (and renewing them is done seamlessly).
This is not an answer to your question but it is IMHO much easier than the approach you are taking.

Comment: Depending on how they configured this and on the token format used you could probably extract the certificates from the security token.  You should just be aware that if you do this automatically for all tokens (p.e. add certificate if not yet known) then you create a security hole since anybody can send you a validly signed SAML2 token (or JWT token for that matter).  If you do it yourself in a controlled way ("I'm now going to get the public key of this Identity provider I know and trust") then this could help you out.

Comment: Yes, I was talking about a manual extraction at some point in time.